# Guest User Create and Update permission after Spring '20

Tags: profile, security, guest-user, spring-20

During Spring '20 Salesforce is deploying a set of security updates regarding the Guest User profile and its capabilities, mainly limiting it from being able to create and update records.

We have many VF Pages, Visual Flows and Lightning components that use these capabilities, for example letting a Contact accept some Terms and Conditions by clicking on a link in an email template.
Is there any workaround for the new security updates that will still allow us to this?

Comment: In past using a custom object plus process builder would work for update.  I still need to test this to confirm it still works

Comment: @gorav if this new update is on the profile level PB will not be able to overcome it